# Fiber output analysis: uniform intensity of an image

Tags: image-processing

I have an image of a fiber output:
[image: 1]

I want to verify 2 factors from this image:

1. How uniform is the intensity across the image (Theoretically fiber output should be closer to a step index profile than a gradient profile - again it depends on how it is illuminated, lets assume it should be closer to flat top)
2. Does the bright spot lie closer to the center

Code for now,

```
data = Total[ImageData[ColorConvert[P2C, "Grayscale"]]];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Filling -> Bottom, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/4, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: 2]

Further, I can also take 3 cropped sections from top to bottom and see the variations in flatness:

[image: 00]
[image: 11]
[image: 33]

This would give me the overall understanding of the variation in intensity distribution and the small bump corresponds to the bright spot, by which I can determine if it is closer to the center.

Is there a better analysis method I can implement? I should be able to quantify what is good and bad criteria from this. That the flatness is faithful allover the image.

Comment: Are you looking for angluar or field homogeneity of the fiber?

Comment: @Eisbär Field homogeneity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

such a clean image we can easily edge detect the circle and its center..

```
EdgeDetect@Binarize@img
```

[image]

```
{cent, rad} = 
 1 /. ComponentMeasurements[%, {"Centroid", "MeanCentroidDistance"}]
```

> {{225.559, 223.983}, 214.327}

```
Show[{Graphics[
   Inset[ImageReflect@img, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, ImageDimensions[img]], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, ImageDimensions[img][[2]]}, {0, 
      ImageDimensions[img][[3]]}}], 
  Graphics[{Red, Circle[cent, rad]}]}]
```

[image]

not sure what you want to do, but here is for example a plot of intensity vs radius:

```
ListPlot[Flatten[
  MapIndexed[{ Norm[#2 - cent] , #} & , 
   ImageData[ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"]] , {2}], 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to measure if the intensity is unifrom (flat) accross the image surface, except for the center peak. Another question: What version of Mathematica are you using, my `ComponentMeasurements[
 EdgeDetect@Binarize@P2C, {"Centroid", "MeanCentroidDistance"}]`gave `1 -> {{216.408, 368.551}, 147.419}` as `{cent, radius}`, which is quite absurd for the same image.

Comment: v 10.1 .  Really you could do well to manually eyeball the center and radius if the `ComponentMeasurements` doesn't work. Most of the images I work with aren't clean enough for that to work and that's what I have to do.

Comment: Yeah, I can eyeball but was surprised to find out such a discrepancy with your result and mine.

Comment: maybe a difference between your original image and the copy off the web..? I put a couple of intermediate steps up to see.